# How to use UISearchView with a pop up in iOS, with Swift4

Tags: uisearchbar, ios11, xcode9, swift4

Hi all I am editing an iOS application which is made with Xcode8, Swift3. I started editing it with Xcode9, Swift4. It runs almost fine, except the pop up. There is a pop up and inside that pop up it has a UISearchView. The issue is when I click on the search bar, it disappears and appears in the top of the screens, as shown in the images.

[This is how it appears when the pop up appears, before click on the search bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIrrT.png)

[This is how it appears when search bar is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrZSE.png)

Here is my code to add that pop up.

```
 self.countrySearchController = ({

        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tb.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
```

[This is the pop up view's xib file's content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBQuI.png)

I want to keep the search bar in side the header of the table after clicking on it too. No questions posted here before was useful. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you!